# How to remove element from array after array was modified

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Recently in my aplication I was having problems with **splice()** from javascript and im telling you why.

Scenario: The user can add products to an array (shopping cart) and Im storing all of the products in a array of json objects. If the user wants to delete an specific product im using the "splice(index,1)" to remove the element with the specified index to be deleted from the array.

EDIT: For example I have this array

```
Products: [{ID: 1, Product: Cake, Qty: 2},{ID:2, Product: Donut, Qty: 1}]
```

---

So in the array there are index[0] and index[1]. When I use splice() to delete the element from index[0] (where is Cake) it does not remove the element, and sometimes it does, I dont know why. This is the function to remove the element from the array

```
function DeleteProduct(indexArray) {
//index array is send from $.each function I have to print the elements of the array
        ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.splice(indexArray, 1);

        //Im removing the <tr> tag from a table, and the index help me to do it and everything here is fine
        $("#tr" + indexArray).remove();


        $.each(ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems, function (index, Products) {
            //After splice I will have the option to recalculate the total of the purchase
            var Total = Number(Products.Precio) * Number(Products.Cantidad);

        });
      }
```

**But for some reason if I try to delete an element from the array with the quantity more than 1 (after the code of the function AddItem()) it "deletes" the element but it still appears existing (even if after the quantity update Im having just one element)**

Sorry for the bad explanation, Im not a native english speaker so It's difficult for me to explain it better.
**EDIT** I simplify my question, hope this help.

**EDIT2: I think the problem was the order of the indexes after splice(). I did not realize after each splice the indexes change, but I left the output as the same, so sometimes I tried to delete an index that was out of range o not existing. My mistake.
Thanks for the help and sorry for my poor question. I'll try to improve**

Comment: could you try to simplify your question?

Comment: Thanks for the respone, I simplify my question hoping to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
// Your array

> x = [{ID: 1, Product: 'Cake', Qty: 2},{ID:2, Product: 'Donut', Qty: 1}]
=> [Object, Object]


// I remove the first element

> x.shift()
=> Object {ID: 1, Product: "Cake", Qty: 2}


// I "print" the array with the first element removed
> x
[ Object
  ID: 2
  Product: "Donut"
  Qty: 1
  __proto__: Object
]
```

I did this in Chrome console, is this what you ask?

Comment: Well yes, but this array is "static" because Cake has quantity of 2, but the complete process Im doing is: 
1. Add the product cake (where the array is created)
2. If the product cake is the same as one already existing, it will update its quantity to the ORIGINAL array (cake =2)
3. IF i want to remove or delete with splice() something is messing with my code that sometimes it looks like it just substract the quantity and not the element from the array. Hope i could be clear

Comment: Thanks for your time juanpastas, the problem was my logic and not realize that after each splice() the array will change the indexes of the array. Thanks.